# How to extract json data from csv file in R

Tags: json, r, csv

I am trying to extract JSON data from a CSV file in R. I am new to both JSON and R, so really need some help.

I have a CSV file, which has 3 columns - 2 columns are `name` and `published_date`. The third column `ratings` however consists of data in JSON format. I am trying to extract that data such that in all I have one CSV file with pure columns (no more JSON format). Can someone please help?

```
Data - 
**name** -> Test1         **published_date**-> 1151367060   **ratings** ->
[{'id': 7, 'name': 'Funny', 'count': 19645}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Beautiful', 'count': 4573}, {'id': 9, 'name': 'Ingenious', 'count': 6073}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Courageous', 'count': 3253}, {'id': 11, 'name': 'Longwinded', 'count': 387}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Confusing', 'count': 242}, {'id': 8, 'name': 'Informative', 'count': 7346}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'Fascinating', 'count': 10581}, {'id': 21, 'name': 'Unconvincing', 'count': 300}, {'id': 24, 'name': 'Persuasive', 'count': 10704}, {'id': 23, 'name': 'Jaw-dropping', 'count': 4439}, {'id': 25, 'name': 'OK', 'count': 1174}, {'id': 26, 'name': 'Obnoxious', 'count': 209}, {'id': 10, 'name': 'Inspiring', 'count': 24924}]
```

Comment: Can you provide the csv data somewhere ? as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) for example ? 
I think single quote is not valid json, so I am not sure you provide a good example

Comment: use `rjson` package. Have you installed one?

Answer (score 0):

First, here is how you can parse your json data

```r
# if you read the data in a table with 3 column and 1 line
tab <- data.frame(name = "Test1",
           published_date = "1151367060",
           ratings ="[{'id': 7, 'name': 'Funny', 'count': 19645}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Beautiful', 'count': 4573}, {'id': 9, 'name': 'Ingenious', 'count': 6073}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Courageous', 'count': 3253}, {'id': 11, 'name': 'Longwinded', 'count': 387}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Confusing', 'count': 242}, {'id': 8, 'name': 'Informative', 'count': 7346}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'Fascinating', 'count': 10581}, {'id': 21, 'name': 'Unconvincing', 'count': 300}, {'id': 24, 'name': 'Persuasive', 'count': 10704}, {'id': 23, 'name': 'Jaw-dropping', 'count': 4439}, {'id': 25, 'name': 'OK', 'count': 1174}, {'id': 26, 'name': 'Obnoxious', 'count': 209}, {'id': 10, 'name': 'Inspiring', 'count': 24924}]",
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Use jsonlite for parsing json
library(jsonlite)
# single quote is invalid, so if real, you need to replace them all by double quote
tab$ratings <- gsub("'", "\"", tab$ratings)
# parse the json
rating <- fromJSON(tab$ratings)
rating
#>    id         name count
#> 1   7        Funny 19645
#> 2   1    Beautiful  4573
#> 3   9    Ingenious  6073
#> 4   3   Courageous  3253
#> 5  11   Longwinded   387
#> 6   2    Confusing   242
#> 7   8  Informative  7346
#> 8  22  Fascinating 10581
#> 9  21 Unconvincing   300
#> 10 24   Persuasive 10704
#> 11 23 Jaw-dropping  4439
#> 12 25           OK  1174
#> 13 26    Obnoxious   209
#> 14 10    Inspiring 24924
```

You can keep this parsing within the input table by using
`tidyverse` piped workflow and tibbles. Using the ability to create list
column, you can store the `fromJSON` result in the table in place of the json string

```r
library(tidyverse)
tab %>%
  # convert to tibble for nice printing
  as_tibble() %>%
  # work on ratings column
  mutate(
    # replace single quote
    ratings = gsub("'", "\"", ratings),
    # create a list column with the result
    ratings= list(jsonlite::fromJSON(ratings))
  ) %>%
  # unnest the list column
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 14 x 5
#>    name  published_date    id name1        count
#>    <chr> <chr>          <int> <chr>        <int>
#>  1 Test1 1151367060         7 Funny        19645
#>  2 Test1 1151367060         1 Beautiful     4573
#>  3 Test1 1151367060         9 Ingenious     6073
#>  4 Test1 1151367060         3 Courageous    3253
#>  5 Test1 1151367060        11 Longwinded     387
#>  6 Test1 1151367060         2 Confusing      242
#>  7 Test1 1151367060         8 Informative   7346
#>  8 Test1 1151367060        22 Fascinating  10581
#>  9 Test1 1151367060        21 Unconvincing   300
#> 10 Test1 1151367060        24 Persuasive   10704
#> 11 Test1 1151367060        23 Jaw-dropping  4439
#> 12 Test1 1151367060        25 OK            1174
#> 13 Test1 1151367060        26 Obnoxious      209
#> 14 Test1 1151367060        10 Inspiring    24924
```

Created on 2018-01-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Comment: Thank you @reprex package. This is really helpful :) What if I had to read a file.csv in R which contains multiple similar rows of data? How do you get one file output in that case?

Comment: Can you provide an example?